# insertAdjacentElement adds only one element, when insertAdjacentHTML adds four

Tags: javascript, function, foreach, createelement, insertadjacenthtml

So i wanted my webpage to create one dot button for every photo that was placed by me in a slides NodeList. **Instead**, it just creates **just one** dot, just like if there was just one image, **but there are 4** images actually.

```js
const dotContainer = document.querySelector('.dots');
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
// images are name slides!

const createDots = function () {
  const dot = document.createElement('button');
  dot.classList.add('dots__dot');
  slides.forEach((s, i) => {
    dotContainer.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', dot);

  });
  const dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dots__dot');
  dots.forEach((d, i) => (d.dataset.slide = `${i}`));
};

createDots();
```

```
    console.log(s); // NodeList(4) [div.slide, div.slide, div.slide, div.slide]
```

[HTML view after using insertAdjacentElement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W3yC.png)

But when i used insertAdjacentHTML... it worked!

```js
const createDots = function () {
  const dot = document.createElement('button');
  dot.classList.add('dots__dot');
  slides.forEach((s, i) => {
    // dotContainer.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', dot);
    dotContainer.insertAdjacentHTML(
      'beforeend',
      `<button class="dots__dot" data-slide="0"></button>`
    );
  });
  const dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dots__dot');
  dots.forEach((d, i) => (d.dataset.slide = `${i}`));
};
createDots();
```

[HTML view after using insertAdjacentHTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMGdr.png)

**Why?**

Comment: An element can only be in the DOM once. You have to create a new "dot" each time you want to add it to the page.

Comment: Put your `createElement` call inside the `forEach` loop to overcome Pointy's point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to add the **same** element several times. You need to create a new element at every `foreach` callback before inserting it

Comment: Ohh! It was so simple. All i had to do is to `forEach` just 2 lines above!
Thank you very much!